# In ASP.NET MVC, how do I post values from multiple dropdowns into a collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

In ASP.NET MVC, I would like to have a view which displays any number of dropdowns as defined in a collection.  Each dropdown has an ID value associated with it.  I would like to then receive these in a post method in the controller where a collection would have all the dropdowns ID values along with the dropdown value selected for each one.

For example, ratings would be a Text/Value collection which would have an arbitrary number of values.

```
   @rating(1).Text  @Html.DropDownList("rating(1)", ratingList, "")
   @rating(2).Text  @Html.DropDownList("rating(2)", ratingList, "")
   ...
   @rating(10).Text  @Html.DropDownList("rating(10)", ratingList, "")
```

It's possible that the rating ID numbers will not be contiguous.  I would like to have a controller method which would return this in a collection such as a Dictionary object.  How can I do this?

Comment: How is your collection of ratings defined initially? `@rating(1)` is not valid syntax, so I'm assuming you mean something along the lines of `@rating[N]` where `rating` would be a list of *something*. It's that "something" that you need to lay out.

Comment: My rating object is just meant to be some collection of an ID and a description.  Each dropdown has that ID associated with it which is to be tied to the value selected in that dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at [`Model Binding to a List`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

And then:

```
@rating[0].Text  @Html.DropDownList("rating[0]", ratingList, "")
@rating[1].Text  @Html.DropDownList("rating[1]", ratingList, "")
...
@rating[9].Text  @Html.DropDownList("rating[9]", ratingList, "")
```

And your controller action could take a `string[] rating` parameter which will contain the selected values.